# Expect.assertions in async/await function

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, jestjs, assertion

From Jest documentation:

> `Expect.assertions(number)` verifies that a certain number of assertions
>   are called during a test. This is often useful when testing
>   asynchronous code, in order to make sure that assertions in a callback
>   actually got called.

That means, if we are testing *reject* cases for `promises`(assertions in `catch`), without `expect.assertions` `promise` may be resolved and our test *will pass*. However, we simply got no errors inside test function and our assertion actually never run. In other words, we didn't check what we wanted. We got the answer but not to our question, cause **fulfilled `promise` would not fail the test**. To sum up, defining number of assertion when checking rejections/errors is a must.

There is another example in docs:

```
test('the data is peanut butter', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const data = await fetchData();
  expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
});
```

As we are using `async/await` pattern, we will wait for `promise` to be resolved and our testing condition will certainly run.

What's the purpose of `expect.assertions` here? Do we really need `expect.assertions` in this code or is it just a best practice to write it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are exactly right.

Using `expect.assertions` is necessary *when testing for rejected Promises using a `catch`*.

Using `expect.assertions` is not necessary when testing for resolved Promises or when testing for rejected Promises using [`.rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#rejects).

For a simple test like this `expect.assertions` is not particularly useful.  For more complex asynchronous tests it can sometimes be useful to add `expect.assertions` as an additional safeguard to ensure the test is behaving as expected.